# sql rows to columns but in one line

Tags: t-sql

i have the following table

```
A                           B


mp1                     Y3013H301
mp2                     924071
mp2                     930081
mp3                     200130543
mp4                     3726474
mp5                     15/2014
mp5                     16/2014
mp6                     BBB032232
mp6                     BBB032572
mp6                     BBB032574
mp6                     BBB0325711
```

i would like to have the following output , indiferent on the number of A or B's :

```
A                   B

mp1                Y3013H301
mp2                924071 ; 930081
mp3                200130543
mp4                3726474
mp5                15/2014 ; 16/2014
mp6                BBB032232 ; BBB032572 ; BBB032574 ; BBB0325711
```

is there any way to do this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question has been answered before. Check out the answers to these questions on SO: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20057655/249353), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2046037/249353), [three](http://stackoverflow.com/q/273238/249353). These should get you started!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `FOR XML PATH('')` in the inner query to get all the values of `B` for each `A`.

```
select distinct T1.A,
    (select STUFF( (select ' ; ' + T2.B 
                from mytable T2
                where T1.A = T2.A
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 3, '')) AS B
from mytable T1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d02a/3)